# How can set functions change values when Java is pass-by-value?

Tags: java, methods

I've heard from many people that Java is a pass-by-value language. If so, how can a set function change a variable's value?

Comment: It uses the method argument to change a field in the object.  There is no need to change the argument itself.

Comment: Then isn't there any way to change a private variable inside a class?

Comment: A private variable can be accessed and changed inside that Class.

Comment: does java have a pass by reference? if so thats what you need, never used java so cant confirm if java includes this

Comment: @WhatsThePoint [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: but,guys, the thing that confused me was that I thought a function couldn't change the actual value if the variable wasn't in its scope. But when I use a set function to change the value of an int and get it with a get function, i get the new value. how so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Java we use accessors to accomplish this.

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/967768

and [this](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) is a good reference to understand pass-by-value and how to test for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply, it really helped me understand!

Comment: @AhmetEmreBoyacı you can mark this as the answer if it helped. Thanks!